# ffmpeg nodejs lambda crop issue

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function to crop videos with ffmpeg

I am installing the layer this way

```sh
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p layer
cd layer
rm -rf *
curl -O https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/builds/ffmpeg-git-amd64-static.tar.xz
tar -xf ffmpeg-git-amd64-static.tar.xz
mv ffmpeg-git-*-amd64-static ffmpeg
rm ffmpeg-git-amd64-static.tar.xz
```

I do not really which version but should be recent as I did it today for the last time

Then my node js lambda function is running with the following nodejs module https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg

```js
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        ffmpeg(inputFile.name)
            .videoFilters(`crop=${width}:${height}:${x}:${y}`)
            .format('mp4')
            .on('error', reject)
            .on('end', () => resolve(fs.readFileSync(outputFile.name)))
            .save(outputFile.name);
```

with for example `videoFilters('crop=500:500:20:20')`

And I have the folowing error

```
ffmpeg exited with code 1: Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
Conversion failed!
```

On my local computer I am running the following command on the exact same image

```sh
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter:v "crop=500:500:20:20" out.mp4
```

my version of ffmpeg is 4.2.2 and this is working great

I do not have the issue with all videos, here one video which is causing me the issue https://ajouve-util.s3.amazonaws.com/earth.mp4

Comment: So it looks like you're passing an invalid argument to .videoFilters. Did you check the width, height, x and y value on fail? Pass the values when you reject.

Comment: I do not think this is an argument issue, this is working with others videos with the exact same arguments

Comment: Can you put the argument `crop=${width}:${height}:${x}:${y}` in a variable, log it and paste here? I'd agree that this is most probably the case. If you calculate the w/h and crop values there may be something `500.1` which would give exactly that outcome.

Comment: Try using ffprobe for finding out the exact width and height of the video.

Answer (score 2):

Here is slightly modified code that works:

```
var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');

var reject = function(something) {
    console.error("got error", something);
}

var resolve = function() {
    console.info("Good, job done. Now read output file");
}

var width = 500;
var height = 500;
var x = 20;
var y = 20;
var filter_string = `crop=${width}:${height}:${x}:${y}`;
console.log("filter_string", filter_string);

var onStart = function(commandLine) {
    console.log('Spawned Ffmpeg with command: ' + commandLine);
}

var command = ffmpeg('earth.mp4')
    .videoFilters(filter_string)
    .format('mp4')
    .on('error', reject)
    .on('end', resolve)
    .on('start', onStart)
    .output('earth_cropped.mp4');

console.log("running..");
command.run();
console.log("Done");
```

With `earth.mp4` downloaded from your link in same dir output is:

```
node main.js
filter_string crop=500:500:20:20
running..
Done
Spawned Ffmpeg with command: ffmpeg -i earth.mp4 -y -filter:v crop=500:500:20:20 -f mp4 earth_cropped.mp4
Good, job done. Now read output file
```

And we get `earth_cropped.mp4` file as expected.

I bet the error is in input params, so add `.on('start', onStart)` in your code and check logs to see exact command used to validate it ;)

Comment: I think the issue is due to some memory issue on lambda

Comment: @Ajouve can you check logs to see exact command used to validate it?

Comment: @Ajouve then complete this QA session. Other people will find this question without proper answer.

Comment: thanks for you help but I have the same issue with your code on lambda